# One event handler function not getting triggered after the execution of another event handler function defined in the same js file

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I am trying to build a static todo app, this app stores the todo list in localStorage (browser memory).

there are 3 elements related to the error - 1 element is causing the error and the other 2 being affected by it.

1. a hide complete checkbox - hides the completed tasks when checked. (element causing the error)
2. complete todo checkbox - mark a todo as completed when checked.
3. delete note button - deletes a note.

I have attached the code files and screenshot, to get an overall idea about the problem and the code.
along with this, I have stored my code in this repo: https://github.com/AbhishekTomr/Todo

Problem - Once the hide completed checkbox is triggered, the complete todo and delete todo mechanism stops working.

Can someone please help me in fixing the code or let me know what is causing the issue?

Screenshot:

[image: description and view of elements causing the error]

```js
//js file : todoFunctions.js 

//function for getting value stored in todoList
let getTodo = function(){
    return Boolean(localStorage.getItem("todo"))?JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo")):[];
}

//function to add or render any list on the screen
let render = function(list){
    document.querySelector("#td").innerHTML = "";
    list.forEach(function(item){
        newTask(item);
        }
    )
}

//function for saving the task in the local storage
let saveTask = function(todo){
    let tdList = JSON.stringify(todo);
    localStorage.setItem("todo",tdList); //setting value for the first time or updating it
}


let newTask = function(node)
{
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    let status = document.createElement("input");
    let remove = document.createElement("button");
    li.textContent = node.td;

    remove.setAttribute("class","remove");
    remove.textContent="Delete";
    

    status.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
    status.setAttribute("class","status");
    status.checked = node.status;
    li.style.textDecoration = (node.status)?"line-through":"none";

    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class","task");
    div.setAttribute("id",node.index);



    div.appendChild(status);
    div.appendChild(li);
    div.appendChild(remove);
    document.querySelector("#td").appendChild(div);

    document.getElementById("new-task").value = ""; //clearing the input feild

}

//function for adding a new task
let addTask = function(todo){
    let td = document.getElementById("new-task").value;
    let status = false;
    let node = {td : td,status : status};
    todo.push(node);
    saveTask(todo); // saving it to local storage
    newTask(node);
}

// function for searching out task
let searchTask = function(todo,e){
    let searchList = todo.filter(function(item){
        return item.td.includes(e.target.value);
    })
    render(searchList); // showing the searched terms on the go..
}


//funtion to delete task
let deleteTodo=function(e,index,todo){
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
    todo.splice(index,1);
    saveTask(todo);
}

//funtion for completing and undoing a task
let changeStatus = function(e,index,todo){
    let state = e.target.checked;
    let td = e.target.parentElement.children[1];
    td.style.textDecoration = (state)?"line-through":"none";
    todo[index].status = state;
    saveTask(todo);
}

//function for hiding complete task
let hideCompleted = function(e,todo){
    if(e.target.checked)
    {
        let filterLst = todo.filter(function(item){
            return !item.status;
        })
     render(filterLst);
    }else{
        render(todo);
    }

}


//js file :main.js
let todo = getTodo(); // get the todo List from storage
render(todo); // display the initial todo List 

//functionality for the different events

document.getElementById("add-task").addEventListener("click",function(e){ //event when the add new task button is pressed
    addTask(todo);  //funtion for adding new task and displaying it on page
})

document.getElementById("search-txt").addEventListener("input",function(e){ //event for text typed in seach bar
    searchTask(todo,e); //funtion for searching the tasks and displaying it on page
})




//event to delete todo 
let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".remove");
btns.forEach(function(item,index){
    item.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        deleteTodo(e,index,todo);
    })
})

//event for complete/uncomplete task
let check = document.querySelectorAll(".status");
check.forEach(function(item,index){
    item.addEventListener("change",function(e){
        changeStatus(e,index,todo);
        console.log("i am triggered");
    })
})

document.querySelector("#hide-check").addEventListener("change",function(e){  //event when hide completed is checked and unchecked
   hideCompleted(e,todo);
})
```

```css
/* css file : main.css */

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  font-family: monospace;
}
main{
  margin: 5px;
}
h1{

  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}
#td-options{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  width: 250px;
}
#search,#search input{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#hide-completed{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
#hide-check{
  margin: 10px;
}
#todo{
  /* border: 3px solid pink; */
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.task{
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.task li{
  list-style-position: inside;
  margin: .5rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.task button{
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: whitesmoke;
}
.task button:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
#add-todo{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 255px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 25px;
}
#add-todo button{
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!-- html file: index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Todo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <!-- mainheading -->
        <h1>My Todo App</h1>

        <!--todoOptions-->
        <div id="td-options">
            <div id="search">
                <input type="text" id="search-txt" placeholder="search your Todo">
            </div>
            <div id="hide-completed">
                <label for="hide-check">
                  Hide Completed Tasks
                </label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="hide-check" name="hide">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- todo list -->
        <div id="todo">
                <ol id="td"></ol>
        </div>

        <!-- add todo -->
        <div id="add-todo">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add A New To Do Task" id="new-task">
            <button id="add-task">Add ToDo</button>
        </div>

        <!-- js files -->
        <script src="todoFunctions.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function render goes through a list and creates the relevant elements for a task to show it on the screen and then appends them.

At the start a list is collected from localstorage and then all the required event listeners are added.

When hideCompleted is called it creates a list from the remaining elements that are not completed, or just uses the complete todo list, and re-renders it. This creates all the elements OK so everything looks alright on the screen.

BUT no event listeners are added so the delete button and so on do not do anything.

My suggestion would be to make the event listener creation code for .remove etc into a function. Call that on start up and when you recreate the list on screen.

Comment: I tried adding the events for delete and complete a todo inside newTask function still the same issue is coming, can u elaborate more upon your solution?

Comment: Can you try implementing my suggestion. Make a function which is called at the start and when a new list is shown which adds the event listeners. I wasn’t recommending adding them in new task Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: thanks a lot this worked for me, I have wrapped all these even listeners in a function and I called it inside the render function(each time the list is displayed on the page), and now it's working!!! thanks again mate .